# Paste pictures as non-links and retain their location

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with many pictures, but the pictures are links and I need to send the file outside our company, to someone who won't have access to the link location.

I am trying to write code to paste the images as non-links and retain their current location in the excel sheet.

The following code fails on the .**`PasteSpecial`** line.

```
Sub test()
Dim Pic As Shape,Lt As Double, Tp As Double
For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes

   Lt = Pic.Left
   Tp = Pic.Top
   Pic.Cut

   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Selection.Top = Tp
        Selection.Left = Lt

    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

Next Pic
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to see what code gets generated when you do it manually?

Comment: Just curious, are the links Hyperlinks? Would it be better to loop through the pics and delete the hyperlinks?  This is using the macro recorder to delete hyperlink for one pic...`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select: Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete` You would just need to loop through the pics using this method. If that is the links you are referring to.